# Set AWS S3 ACL per object with Django Storages

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I am using django storages with the `AWS_DEFAULT_ACL` set to `public read`.

However I want to be able to manually save files with `default_storage.save()` with `private` ACL.

Is there a way to do this with default_storage?

Something like:

```
default_storage.save(file_name, ContentFile(content), acl='private')
```